# String the values instead of printing them during recursion

Tags: python, recursion

So I wrote this piece of code to print all root leaf paths of a binary tree and when it hits the base case it prints each path, instead I would like to store it in a list so that in the end I have a list of lists containing each path. I have tried several things like using tail recursion or using another global list but I am unable to implement it correctly.

```
def rootleafPath(self, root):
    global arr
    if root is None:
        return
    arr.append(root.rootid)
    if self.isLeaf(root):
        print arr
    self.rootleafPath(root.left)
    self.rootleafPath(root.right)
    arr.pop()
```

This returns

```
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 3]
```

while I want my function to return a list like [[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3]]

I am having this problem in most of my recursive solutions where I need to store a result when it hits the base case instead of printing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive path algorithm should return a list of lists at each step. If you're at a leaf node, it should return a list with one list containing the id of that node. Otherwise, it should add the current node's id to each of the lists returned by the left or right nodes and then return this new list. Sort of hard to explain, so I wrote some code :)

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, root_id, left=None, right=None):
        self.root_id = root_id
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def is_leaf(self):
        if self.left or self.right:
            return False
        return True

def path(node):
    if node.isLeaf():
        return [[node.root_id]]
    left_paths = [[node.root_id] + p for p in path(node.left)] if node.left else []
    right_paths = [[node.root_id] + p for p in path(node.right)] if node.right else []
    return left_paths + right_paths

tree = Node(0,Node(1, Node(2), Node(3, right=Node(4))), Node(5, Node(6)))

path(tree) => [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3, 4], [0, 5, 6]]
```

Using a global array is difficult because at each level of recursion, you'd have to know the state of the program. It's far easier to break the problem down into two steps:

1. If I'm at a leaf node, what do I have to return that represents the tree if this leaf node were the only node in the tree
2. If I'm at a node with children, what should they return to me so that I can fully represent my subtree.

In this case, the leaf node should return a list of a single list containing it's id:
    return [[node.root_id]]

And if the node is somewhere inside the tree, it should be expecting lists of lists from its children that describe the subtree. It should then add its id as the first element of each sublist and then return the concatenated result of all its children's lists.

I hope this helps!